# g++ generates undefined instruction(ud2) when trying to access 0x00 from kernel

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, osdev

I'm trying to write a small Kernel. This code is executing in 32-bit Protected mode with paging and interrupts disabled.

As the title suggests when I try to access `0x00` from my Kernel, the compiler generates `ud2` (undefined instruction) causing a triple fault.

This is the dissasembly of the function when I try to access `0x00`

```
void SetupX64Paging()
{
  100070:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  100072:   8d b4 26 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
  100079:   8d b4 26 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
    // The paging directory will be at 0x00h
    uint64_t *pageDirBase = (uint64_t *)0x00;
    //uint64_t *pageDirBase = (uint64_t *)0x00007BFF;

    // clear area for 4 tables (16KB)
    for(uint64_t i = 0; i < 512 * 4; i++)
        pageDirBase[i] = 0;
  100080:   c7 00 00 00 00 00       movl   $0x0,(%eax)
  100086:   83 c0 04                add    $0x4,%eax
    for(uint64_t i = 0; i < 512 * 4; i++)
  100089:   3d 00 20 00 00          cmp    $0x2000,%eax
  10008e:   75 f0                   jne    100080 <_Z14SetupX64Pagingv+0x10>
    PDPT = (uint64_t *)PML4 + 0x1000;  // 4KB
    PDT  = (uint64_t *)PML4 + 0x2000;  // 8KB
    PT   = (uint64_t *)PML4 + 0x3000;  // 12KB

    // Map each table entry into its parent and set the r/w and present flags
    PML4[0] = (uint64_t)PDPT | 0x3;
  100090:   c7 05 00 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x0
  100097:   00 00 00 
  10009a:   0f 0b                   ud2    
  10009c:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
  10009e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

Although it does not show in the disassembly, `PML4` is initialized to `pageDirBase`
In this setup, the kernel has just jumped to protected mode.
Interrupts are disabled, Paging is disabled.

The code in this file is compiled as :

```
i686-elf-g++ -c Paging.cpp -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -g -I../Common -I../Include
```

Is there a compiler directive that should be used to make compiler not generate undefined instruction.

One peculiar thing to note is that the loop which zeros out the memory at `%eip = 100080` works just fine